# Providing SignTool configuration in Inno Setup script

Tags: inno-setup, code-signing, signing, signtool

I have the following Inno Setup signing configuration:

```
[Setup]
SignTool=signtool $f
SignedUninstaller=yes
```

In Inno Setup Compiler IDE in *"Tools > Configure Sign Tools..."* I have:

```
"C:\DEVELOPMENT\Setup\signtool.exe" sign /f C:\DEVELOPMENT\Signing_Certificate.pfx /p "my_password" $f
```

...this works great on my local machine when I compile my Inno Setup.

However, we need to build installer automatically using TeamCity. So this all have to be automatic. And the sign tool configuration needs to be included in the script, without any need to configure anything upfront.

Is there anyway to declare my paths as variables in the actual Inno Setup script so that they are picked up in the signing wizard line above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For automatic build, do not use Inno Setup IDE. You should use [`iscc` command-line compiler](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=compilercmdline).

For configuring a sign tool, `iscc` has `/S` switch:

```
iscc example.iss "/Ssigntool=C:\DEVELOPMENT\Setup\signtool.exe sign /f C:\DEVELOPMENT\Signing_Certificate.pfx /p my_password $f"
```

Comment: I have it working the way youe described using ISCC (from the Inno Setup 5 directory), with the $p switch...and it pointing to my original .iss file. The signing worked as well. Thank you !